# TinyMCE undo action does not fire change event

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

Not sure if anyone has ever experienced this issue with your TinyMCE.
I have a on change event handler which changes a value of another element.
See the init code below:

```
/** Initialize TinyMCE inline editor for headline text */
tinymce.init({
    selector: ".editable.headline",
    paste_as_text: true,
    inline: true,
    toolbar: "undo redo",
    menubar: false,
    verify_html: false,
    font_formats: "MuseoSans = sans-serif;",
    setup: function(ed) {
        var text = '';
        var wordlimit = 200;
        /** handler for keydown event to prevent < 200 character limit */
        ed.on('keydown',function(e) {
            text = ed.getContent().replace(/(< ([^>]+)<)/g, '');
            wordcount = wordlimit - (text.length);
               if(wordcount <= 0 && e.keyCode != 8) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
               }
        });
        /** handler for headline text changes */
        ed.on('change',function(e) {
            var content = tinyMCE.get(ed.id).getContent();
            var escapedClassName = ed.id.replace(/(\[|\])/g, '\\$&');
            $('.'+escapedClassName).html(content);

        });
   }
});
```

When I type/paste text the `change` event fire properly, however when I undo the text changes the `change` event does not fire properly.

Any ideas how I can force fire the `change` event on undo and redo events?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The content is not super easy to find, but the TinyMCE website does describe a list of [events that are fired during the course of the editor's lifecycle](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/) and explains when those events are fired.

In your scenario, simply add the **redo** and **undo** events to the `on` function call you have within the `setup` function.

```
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.on('change redo undo',function(e) {
        var content = tinyMCE.get(ed.id).getContent();
        var escapedClassName = ed.id.replace(/(\[|\])/g, '\\$&');
        $('.'+escapedClassName).html(content);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just FYI, I had the same issue when changing the URL of a link (it was not triggering any events) and I solved by just firing the event manually:

```
 tinymce.activeEditor.fire('change');
```

Comment: Could you please explain how you implemented this?

Comment: Sorry but that was long ago, I forgot all the details and I have no access to that codebase anymore